# connecting GUI to pipeline in Qt and standard c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, visual-c++

My question is about linking Qt and win32 application
The problem is this:
My colleague wrote a special program which uses pipeline. This pipeline is used to send special messages to GUI. And GUI must show these messages on display. The pipe line program has a thread inside it. This thread always is running and listening  to internal messages. Whenever a message received it create a new thread and this thread must comminucate with GUI and display the message, then killed (He said this routine must be followed).
This is his code for such using

```
DWORD WINAPI PipeThread( void* pContext )
   {

    BOOL   fConnected = FALSE; 
    DWORD  dwThreadId = 0; 
    HANDLE hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, hThread = NULL; 
    LPTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\InterfacePipe"); 



    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)malloc(SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
    if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
    {
        DWORD er = ::GetLastError();
    }
    if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, TRUE, (PACL)0, FALSE))
    {
        DWORD er = ::GetLastError();
    }
    sa.nLength = sizeof sa;
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

    for (;;) 
    { 
        //_tprintf( TEXT("\nPipe Server: Main thread awaiting client connection on %s\n"), lpszPipename);
        hPipe = CreateNamedPipe( 
            lpszPipename,             // pipe name 
            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,       // read/write access 
            PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message type pipe 
            PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message-read mode 
            PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode 
            PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances  
            BUFFER_SIZE,                  // output buffer size 
            BUFFER_SIZE,                  // input buffer size 
            0,                        // client time-out 
            &sa);                    // default security attribute 

        if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        {
            //_tprintf(TEXT("CreateNamedPipe failed, GLE=%d.\n"), GetLastError()); 
            return -1;
        }

        // Wait for the client to connect; if it succeeds, 
        // the function returns a nonzero value. If the function
        // returns zero, GetLastError returns ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED. 

        fConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) ? 
TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED); 

        if (fConnected) 
        { 
            // Create a thread for this client. 
            hThread = CreateThread( 
                NULL,              // no security attribute 
                0,                 // default stack size 
                InstanceThread,    // thread proc
                (LPVOID) hPipe,    // thread parameter 
                0,                 // not suspended 
                &dwThreadId);      // returns thread ID 

            if (hThread == NULL) 
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else CloseHandle(hThread); 
        } 
        else 
            // The client could not connect, so close the pipe. 
            CloseHandle(hPipe); 
    } 

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

And the code which uses to display message on MFC dialog is this:
DWORD WINAPI InstanceThread(LPVOID lpvParam)
    // This routine is a thread processing function to read from and reply to a client
    // via the open pipe connection passed from the main loop. Note this allows
    // the main loop to continue executing, potentially creating more threads of
    // of this procedure to run concurrently, depending on the number of incoming
    // client connections.
{ 



    HANDLE hHeap      = GetProcessHeap();
    TCHAR* pchRequest = (TCHAR*)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(TCHAR));
    TCHAR* pchReply   = (TCHAR*)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(TCHAR));

    DWORD cbBytesRead = 0, cbReplyBytes = 0, cbWritten = 0; 
    BOOL fSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hPipe  = NULL;

    // Do some extra error checking since the app will keep running even if this
    // thread fails.z

    if (lpvParam == NULL)
    {
        if (pchReply != NULL) HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchReply);
        if (pchRequest != NULL) HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchRequest);
        return (DWORD)-1;
    }

    if (pchRequest == NULL)
    {
        if (pchReply != NULL) HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchReply);
        return (DWORD)-1;
    }

    if (pchReply == NULL)
    {
        if (pchRequest != NULL) HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchRequest);
        return (DWORD)-1;
    }

    // Print verbose messages. In production code, this should be for debugging only.

    // The thread's parameter is a handle to a pipe object instance. 

    hPipe = (HANDLE) lpvParam; 

    // Loop until done reading
    while (1) 
    { 
        // Read client requests from the pipe. This simplistic code only allows messages
        // up to BUFSIZE characters in length.
        fSuccess = ReadFile( 
            hPipe,        // handle to pipe 
            pchRequest,    // buffer to receive data 
            BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(TCHAR), // size of buffer 
            &cbBytesRead, // number of bytes read 
            NULL);        // not overlapped I/O 

        if (!fSuccess || cbBytesRead == 0)
        {   
            break;
        }

        MyData* data = new MyData;
        data->client_Param = pchRequest;


        HWND handle = FindWindow(NULL,CStringW("MFCApplication1"));
        PostMessage(handle, WM_YOU_HANVE_DATA, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(data) ,NULL);

        // Process the incoming message.
        //GetAnswerToRequest(pchRequest, pchReply, &cbReplyBytes); 

        if (wcscmp(pchRequest,L"msg1")==0)
            StringCchCopy( pchReply, BUFFER_SIZE, TEXT("Hi"));
        else
            StringCchCopy( pchReply, BUFFER_SIZE, TEXT("default echo answer"));

        cbReplyBytes = (lstrlen(pchReply)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR);
        // Write the reply to the pipe. 
        fSuccess = WriteFile( 
            hPipe,        // handle to pipe 
            pchReply,     // buffer to write from 
            cbReplyBytes, // number of bytes to write 
            &cbWritten,   // number of bytes written 
            NULL);        // not overlapped I/O 

        if (!fSuccess || cbReplyBytes != cbWritten)
        {   
            break;
        }
    }

    // Flush the pipe to allow the client to read the pipe's contents 
    // before disconnecting. Then disconnect the pipe, and close the 
    // handle to this pipe instance. 

    FlushFileBuffers(hPipe); 
    DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe); 
    CloseHandle(hPipe); 

    HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchRequest);
    HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchReply);

    return 1;
}
```

As you see he use function instead of method. I create a class and push his methods and use signal and slot to get the goal.
But it breaks down. The reason is that createThread method must get the name of function not the name of method. So I create the method as static method but another error raise. Signal and slot should use a real object(in moc file it use “this” keyword which is not compatible with this method)
How should I overcome this problem

```
PipeCreator::PipeCreator(QObject *parent = 0) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    HANDLE hPipeThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, PipeCreator::PipeThread, NULL, 0, NULL );
}

DWORD PipeCreator::PipeThread(void *pContext)

{
    BOOL   fConnected = FALSE;
    DWORD  dwThreadId = 0;
    HANDLE hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, hThread = NULL;
    LPTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\InterfacePipe");

    // The main loop creates an instance of the named pipe and
    // then waits for a client to connect to it. When the client
    // connects, a thread is created to handle communications
    // with that client, and this loop is free to wait for the
    // next client connect request. It is an infinite loop.

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)malloc(SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
    if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
    {
        DWORD er = ::GetLastError();
    }
    if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, TRUE, (PACL)0, FALSE))
    {
        DWORD er = ::GetLastError();
    }
    sa.nLength = sizeof sa;
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

    for (;;)
    {
hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
            lpszPipename,             // pipe name
            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,       // read/write access
            PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message type pipe
            PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message-read mode
            PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode
            PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances
            BUFFER_SIZE,                  // output buffer size
            BUFFER_SIZE,                  // input buffer size
            0,                        // client time-out
            &sa);                    // default security attribute

        if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        // Wait for the client to connect; if it succeeds,
        // the function returns a nonzero value. If the function
        // returns zero, GetLastError returns ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED.

        fConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) ?
TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED);

        if (fConnected)
        {

            this->instance =new InstanceCreator();
            connect(this->instance,SIGNAL(NewDataAvailable(MyData)),this,SLOT(NewDataAvailableForGUI(MyData)));
                      // Create a thread for this client.
            hThread = CreateThread(
                NULL,              // no security attribute
                0,                 // default stack size
                this->instance->InstanceThread,    // thread proc
                (LPVOID) hPipe,    // thread parameter
                0,                 // not suspended
                &dwThreadId);      // returns thread ID

            if (hThread == NULL)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                //Here I should recieve the emmited signal
                emit NewDataAvailableForGUI(this->newData);
                CloseHandle(hThread);
            }
        }
        else
            // The client could not connect, so close the pipe.
            CloseHandle(hPipe);
    }

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

// This routine is a thread processing function to read from and reply to a client
// via the open pipe connection passed from the main loop. Note this allows
// the main loop to continue executing, potentially creating more threads of
// of this procedure to run concurrently, depending on the number of incoming
// client connections.
DWORD InstanceCreator::InstanceThread(LPVOID lpvParam)

{



HANDLE hHeap      = GetProcessHeap();
TCHAR* pchRequest = (TCHAR*)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(TCHAR));
TCHAR* pchReply   = (TCHAR*)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(TCHAR));

DWORD cbBytesRead = 0, cbReplyBytes = 0, cbWritten = 0;
BOOL fSuccess = FALSE;
HANDLE hPipe  = NULL;

// Do some extra error checking since the app will keep running even if this
// thread fails.z

//PostMessage((HWND)CMFCApplication1Dlg->textBox3->Handle.ToPointer(), WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)L"TestDLL Try");

if (lpvParam == NULL)
{

    if (pchReply != NULL) HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchReply);
    if (pchRequest != NULL) HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchRequest);
    return (DWORD)-1;
}

if (pchRequest == NULL)
{

 if (pchReply != NULL) HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchReply);
    return (DWORD)-1;
}

if (pchReply == NULL)
{

if (pchRequest != NULL) HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchRequest);
    return (DWORD)-1;
}

// Print verbose messages. In production code, this should be for debugging only.
// The thread's parameter is a handle to a pipe object instance.

hPipe = (HANDLE) lpvParam;

// Loop until done reading
while (1)
{
    // Read client requests from the pipe. This simplistic code only allows messages
    // up to BUFSIZE characters in length.
    fSuccess = ReadFile(
        hPipe,        // handle to pipe
        pchRequest,    // buffer to receive data
        BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(TCHAR), // size of buffer
        &cbBytesRead, // number of bytes read
        NULL);        // not overlapped I/O

    if (!fSuccess || cbBytesRead == 0)
    {

break;
    }

    MyData data;
    data.data=QString::fromStdWString(pchRequest);

    emit NewDataAvailable(data);

    // Process the incoming message.
    //GetAnswerToRequest(pchRequest, pchReply, &cbReplyBytes);

    if (wcscmp(pchRequest,L"msg1")==0)
        StringCchCopy( pchReply, BUFFER_SIZE, TEXT("Hi"));
    else
        StringCchCopy( pchReply, BUFFER_SIZE, TEXT("default echo answer"));

    cbReplyBytes = (lstrlen(pchReply)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR);
    // Write the reply to the pipe.
    fSuccess = WriteFile(
        hPipe,        // handle to pipe
        pchReply,     // buffer to write from
        cbReplyBytes, // number of bytes to write
        &cbWritten,   // number of bytes written
        NULL);        // not overlapped I/O

    if (!fSuccess || cbReplyBytes != cbWritten)
    {
        break;
    }
}

// Flush the pipe to allow the client to read the pipe's contents
// before disconnecting. Then disconnect the pipe, and close the
// handle to this pipe instance.

FlushFileBuffers(hPipe);
DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
CloseHandle(hPipe);

HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchRequest);
HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchReply);

return 1;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend switching to QThread, and reading about [how signals are passed between threads in Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html)

Comment: Also I recommend to use QLocalSocket to handle the named pipe with Qt on Windows.

Comment: I know about them but my project manager does not accept to use them. He emphesises that using the Qt just for GUI. All other parts of project must be independent from Qt.